# Why I am not getting Redirected to Another Activity in Android Studio after connecting to Databse

Tags: android

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private EditText editTextUsername, getEditTextPassword;
    private Button buttonLogin;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        if (SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).isLoggedIn()){
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(this, vendorDashboard.class));
            return;
        }

        editTextUsername = findViewById(R.id.editTextUsername);
        getEditTextPassword = findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
        buttonLogin = findViewById(R.id.buttonLogin);

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");

        buttonLogin.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    private void userLogin(){
        final String username = editTextUsername.getText().toString().trim();
        final String password = getEditTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();

        progressDialog.show();

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(
                Request.Method.POST,
                Constants.URL_LOGIN,
                response -> {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();

                    try {
                        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                        if(!obj.getBoolean("error")){
                            SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext())
                                    .userLogin(
                                            obj.getInt("id"),
                                            obj.getString("username"),
                                            obj.getString("email")
                                    );
                            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), vendorDashboard.class));
                            finish();
                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(
                                    getApplicationContext(),
                                    obj.getString("message"),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                            ).show();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                },
                error -> {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();

                    Toast.makeText(
                            getApplicationContext(),
                            error.getMessage(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                    ).show();
                }
        ){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("user_login", username);
                params.put("user_pass", password);
                return params;
            }
        };

        RequestHandler.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(view == buttonLogin){
            userLogin();
        }
    }
}
```

I am using the above code to log in to the WordPress database after clicking Login Button when I try to add a Toast or to startActivity Intent I was unable to do so any suggestion why???

Here is the close look where I'm trying to add the code for a Toast and startActivity Intent

```
                 try {
                        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                        if(!obj.getBoolean("error")){
                            SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext())
                                    .userLogin(
                                            obj.getInt("id"),
                                            obj.getString("username"),
                                            obj.getString("email")
                                    );

                            // **Exactly here**

                            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), vendorDashboard.class));
                            finish();
                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(
                                    getApplicationContext(),
                                    obj.getString("message"),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                            ).show();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                },
                error -> {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();

                    Toast.makeText(
                            getApplicationContext(),
                            error.getMessage(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                    ).show();
                }
```

I think the problem is in this try-catch is mentioned above?

Comment: You are not getting even else Toast message? Also, volley is hardly used, use retrofit.

Comment: retrofit? can you please tell me about this

Comment: You can also use okhttp. And also put some logs, predicting without is almost impossible

Comment: @iharshmgoyal  [Check this for Retrofit](https://medium.com/@prakash_pun/retrofit-a-simple-android-tutorial-48437e4e5a23). its just replacement for volley I just suggested. Are you getting any of the toast message??

Comment: No, not even Toasts

Comment: Ok. 1] try changing onClick if condition as `if(view.getId() == R.id.buttonLogin){userLogin()}`. 2] have you added android.permission.INTERNET in manifest. after this it won't work share the logs

Comment: obviously it is not entering the if condition.. try to debug your code to check every step. btw what's your login URL ? let me try

Comment: @ruben ROOT_LOGIN URL is https://ebharatstores.com/AndroidAppConnection/v1/userLogin.php